# iPad app to detect and download data updates for offline usage

Tags: ios, ipad, download, updates

I need to create an iPad app which firstly saves online content for offline usage but also detects and downloads updates (preferably just the changes due to 3G data costs) when online with possible push notifications. Which would be the best method and where could I learn how to do this as I am new to this area.

I have javascript knowledge and have heard of phonegap/titanium which avoids Objective-C altogether. Or would I need to learn Objective-C from scratch. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question but one that I work with all the time. Our strategy is every time the app is opened, if it is online we check for updated content. We then prompt the user that new content is available and they can choose to download it now or later. You will need to build a mechanism to poll your servers hosting the content and figure out if the content has been updated.